# Flyout menu not available after navigation in MAUI

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, navigation-drawer, maui, .net-maui

I am taking a Xamarin Forms application and converting it over to MAUI.

In Android, I have found that if I navigate to a different page, I lose my flyout button (hamburger button) in the top navigation bar.  I haven't tried it yet in iOS but I assume it is the same behavior.

Here is how I am navigating to my initial page:

```
private void LaunchInitialPage(Page page)
{
    FlyoutPage FlyoutPage = new FlyoutPage
    {
        Detail = new NavigationPage(page)
        {
            BarBackgroundColor = Helpers.Colors.BarBackgroundColor,
            BarTextColor = Color.FromArgb("#ffffff")
        },
        Flyout = new MyDrawerMenu(),
        FlyoutLayoutBehavior = FlyoutLayoutBehavior.Popover
    };
    ((App)Application.Current).MainPage = FlyoutPage;
}
```

The above works like a charm.  My page is rendered correctly, and I see the hamburger menu.

Most of the time, I would want to "back" button to show up at the top of the page when they click on an item.  And that works.  However there are a few pages where a back button doesn't make sense, so I want it removed and instead display the hamburger menu.

Here is how my navigation looks:

```
public async Task LaunchNextPage(Page page)
{
    Page mdp = (((App)Application.Current).MainPage as FlyoutPage).Detail;
    NavigationPage np = (NavigationPage)mdp;

    NavigationPage.SetHasBackButton(page, false);
    await np.PushAsync(page, true);
}
```

This code successfully navigates to the second page.  The back button works as expected, and the `NavigationPage.SetHasBackButton(page,false)` removes the back button from the navigation bar at the top of the screen.

However, I do not see the hamburger menu.  I can still swipe over from the left and reveal the menu, but I really want to see the hamburger show up at the top of the page.

I should note that this did work as I expected in Xamarin.Forms.  It is only when migrating to MAUI that I am seeing this behavior.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I guess it is not flyout that comes with Shell, have you tried that one ?

Comment: Have I tried Shell?  Yes we played around with Shell a bit.  But given the size of the project, it was determined that switching to Shell was outside the scope of the project if we can find a way to get the FlyoutPage to work without it. So I am hoping to be able to figure out why the ```LaunchNextPage``` above isn't working as I believe it should be.

Comment: Do you mean when you hided the back button, the hamburger menu will also be hided? Did you try to debug and check the value of `FlyoutPage.ShouldShowToobarButton()` when you hided the back button?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wasn't able to find a good way to bring the default hamburger button back on request without clearing the page stack, which I didn't want to do for all pages.  So I was able to get this to work by setting the Title View when needed and replicating the navigation bar.

```
public async Task LaunchNextPage(Page page)
{
    NavigationPage.SetHasBackButton(page, false);

    var fop = ((App)App.Current).MainPage as FlyoutPage;
    if (fop.Detail.Navigation.NavigationStack?.ToList()?.Count > 0)
    {
        NavigationPage.SetTitleView(this, new NavigationBar());
    }
    else
    {
        // at the beginning of the stack so already showing the burger menu
        NavigationPage.SetTitleView(this, null);
    }

    NavigationPage np = (NavigationPage)fop.Detail;
    await np.PushAsync(page, true);

    if (NavigationPage.GetTitleView(this) != null)
    {
        (NavigationPage.GetTitleView(this) as NavigationBar).Title = page.Title;
    }
}
```

NavigationBar.xaml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<HorizontalStackLayout
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui" 
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
    x:Class="NavigationBar" 
    VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" 
    HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" 
    Spacing="0"
    Padding="0"
    x:Name="this">

    <ImageButton
        x:Name="imgBurger"
        Source="hamburger_menu_icon.png" 
        WidthRequest="24" 
        HeightRequest="24"
        Margin="0,0,36,0"
        Clicked="imgBurger_Clicked"
        />

    <Label
        x:Name="lblNavBarTitle"
        VerticalOptions="Center"
        FontAttributes="Bold"
        FontSize="Medium" />

</HorizontalStackLayout>
```

NavigationBar.xaml.cs:

```
public partial class NavigationBar : HorizontalStackLayout
{ 
    public NavigationBar()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        lblNavBarTitle.TextColor = Color.FromArgb("#FFFFFF");
        BackgroundColor = Color.FromArgb("#000000");
    }

    public string Title
    {
        set
        {
            lblNavBarTitle.Text = value;
        }
    }

    private void imgBurger_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var fop = ((App)App.Current).MainPage as FlyoutPage;
        fop.IsPresented = !fop.IsPresented;
    }
}
```

Hope this helps somebody!